# Multiple checkboxes in razor (using foreach)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have a problem and I can't find solution.
I'm using Razor and it is my VieModel class.

```
public class GroupToExport
{
    public GroupToExport()
    {
        ToExport = false;
    }

    [DisplayName("Export")]
    public bool ToExport { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }

}

public class GroupsToExport
{
    public GroupsToExport()
    {
        //refill list
    }

    public List<GroupToExport> ExportingGroups { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "ElmahGroup", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "toExportForm" }))
{
//some divs
    <input type="submit" id="js-export-submit" value="Export" />
 @foreach (var item in Model.ExportingGroups)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="js-export-checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.ToExport)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
//some divs
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Export(GroupsToExport model)
    {
        var groupsToExport = model.ExportingGroups.Where(x => x.ToExport).Select(x => x);
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
```

After submit "ToExport", in Controller, every group always has value 'false'. Even if all groups are checked.

Can somebody help me? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How does the data come to you in the model (param). Maybe you should check the name of the checkbox-html.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate controls for a collection. The html you're generating for each checkbox (and for the associated hidden input) is `<input type="checkbox" name="item.ToExport" .../>`. Your model does not contain a property which is named `item`.

Use a `for` loop

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.ExportingGroups.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td class="js-export-checkbox">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExportingGroups[i].ToExport)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Now your HTML will be

```
<input name="ExportingGroups[0].ToExport" .../>
<input name="ExportingGroups[1].ToExport" .../>
```

etc. which will correctly bind to your model

**Edit**

Alternatively you can use a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `GroupToExport`. Create a partial view `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/GroupToExport.cshtml`

```
@model yourAssembly.GroupToExport
<tr>
  <td class="js-export-checkbox">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ToExport)
  </td>
</tr>
```

And then in the main view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExportingGroups)
```

The `EditorFor()` method will generate the correct html for each item in your collection based on the template.

Comment: `You cannot use a foreach loop` - You can if you use an `EditorFor` inside the loop right?

Comment: @jumpingcode, If you use an editor template for typeof `GroupToExport`, the you don't need (and should not be using) a `foreach` loop - its would be just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExportingGroups)`

Comment: I agree, but you have made a sweeping statement that is technically not true

Comment: @jumpingcode, It is true (except if you were to use some dreadful hacks to make it work)

Comment: @jumpingcode, Before you downvote,I suggest you try it

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I thought that a problem was in name of input, but I don't know how to bind it to my model in other way. Thanku you!

Answer (score 4):

You are using Incorrect syntax to Map the values back when they are posted, since the checked value of a checkbox is initialised to false by default, that is the reason why it is always false,use sysntax

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.ExportingGroups.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="js-export-checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.ExportingGroups[i].ToExport)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
 //some divs
```

This should map back all values you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found this works much better: Leave the foreach loop as is (do not user a counter)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GroupToExport)
{
```

Then use this Razor format to display a checkbox

```
@Html.CheckBox("Active", @item.ToExport)
```

Simple to use and does not make you change the typical foreach loop.

Comment: This is MUCH better than the overly-complex answers above.