# MVC 5 HttpPost: Update Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PracticeExercise.Muscle)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PracticeExercise.Execrcise)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PracticeExercise.PlannedSets)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PracticeExercise.PlannedRepeats)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PracticeExercise.Pause)
            </th>


            <th colspan="5">
                Weights
            <th colspan="5">
                Repeats
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PracticeExercise.Muscle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PracticeExercise.Execrcise)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PracticeExercise.PlannedSets)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PracticeExercise.PlannedRepeats)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PracticeExercise.Pause)
                </td>

                <td colspan="5">
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Weights1,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Weights2,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Weights3,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Weights4,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Weights5,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                <td colspan="5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Repeats1,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Repeats2,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                     
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Repeats3,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                      
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Repeats4,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Repeats5,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }
                        
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>

        }

    </table>


    
}
```

Hi,

i created a table with Input from the database. My Input for this Page looks like `@model IEnumerable<HomePageProject.Models.Record>`. As you can see in the code I inserted all Record datasets into the table.
The thing I need help with is that I want to refresh the datasets in the database. Therefore I tried several Controller Methods like `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Edit(Record record)` or `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<HomePageProject.Models.Record> lstRecords)`.
In case of Parameter `Record record` there is a returning `Record` object but with the ID 0 and every other parameter contains the value `null`.

My Plan is to implement the functionalities "save whole list of records" and "save single record". Can you tell me a way to reach this?

Many thanks!

Gr_

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate controls for items in a collection. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113118/multiple-checkboxes-in-razor-using-foreach/32113225#32113225)

Comment: Thanks for the link!
The hint with the for-loop was really well. But now i have the Problem, that everytime i press the submit button, it catches the first element in the List and gives it to the post controller.

Comment: If you using a singe form containing the `for` loop and a submit button it will post back the whole collection, not one. Note you cannot have it both ways - you cant save single records and a list of records. (although you could have a second form for creating a new record that post back to a different controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments:

You cannot use a foreach loop to generate controls for items in a collection. Refer this answer – Stephen Muecke Aug 26 '15 at 10:31

Thanks for the link! The hint with the for-loop was really well. But now i have the Problem, that everytime i press the submit button, it catches the first element in the List and gives it to the post controller. – GR_ Aug 27 '15 at 14:47

If you using a singe form containing the for loop and a submit button it will post back the whole collection, not one. Note you cannot have it both ways - you cant save single records and a list of records. (although you could have a second form for creating a new record that post back to a different controller method. – Stephen Muecke Aug 27 '15 at 23:22

Comment: what if instead of copying and pasting all comments you elaborate your answer for showing the solution?