# Can I modify multiple items in a BeginForm section in a Razor/MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.beginform

I would like to edit a list of items and save them all together in the same submit. Is it possible? If so, how?

I have the following piece of code, but it does not give the wanted result. Or otherwise I don't know what to write for the counterpart in the controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>NewValue</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Value)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

**Update** Thanks to @Jonesopolis I came up with this working solution

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>NewValue</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Id)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Value)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Value)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

For MyController

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<NameDoesNotMatter> newValues)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class NameDoesNotMatter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now see if i can work out the thing with the templates. The link of @StephenMuecke should be sufficient

**Update 2**
Well that's wasn't that hard the code is now

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>NewValue</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorForModel()
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

And for Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TypeOfModel.cshtml

```
@model TypeOfModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.Id)
        @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Value)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.Value)
    </td>
</tr>
```

The controller remains the same

Comment: yes it's very possible.  Use a `for` loop rather than a `foreach` loop here.  Your submit should return the collection back to the controller.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113118/multiple-checkboxes-in-razor-using-foreach/32113225#32113225) for an explanation of why you need a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate`

Comment: I think i can use these answers ... gonna try.

Comment: I'd like to accept one of your answers, but can't accept a comment

Comment: No problem (and I've marked it as a duplicate anyway) - and you can always upvote other answers when you gain the necessary rep

Answer (score 1):

When you just show items using a for loop then the naming convention used in the resulting html tag doesn't match up with what MVC is expecting when it binds the model upon form submit.  The easiest way to fix this is to use @Html.EditorFor and custom editor templates.  Here are a couple of examples:

[ASP.NET MVC DisplayTemplate and EditorTemplates for Entity Framework DbGeography Spatial Types](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx)

[Extending Editor Templates for ASP.NET MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp.net-mvc/)

Comment: I can't find an useful example how to use templates in combination with such for loop