# Get Selected Checkbox on Grid View to Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

I have a grid under foreach statement. This foreach statement has an HTML input checkbox column.

My problem is, I am able to populate my rows and grid properly. All input fields are okay even the checkbox attributes were okay but I cannot get all the "checked" checkbox to pass into the controller as Model.

Here is my HTML/View code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chkEmployee" name="lngEmployeeID" value="="@Model.lngEmployeeID"></input>
```

And this is my JQuery code:

```
function fncBulkApprove() {

        $('#btnEdit').unbind();
        $('#btnEdit').on('click', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var objData = $('form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("fncBulkEdit", Model)',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'application/JSON',
                data: objData,
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                complete: function (request, status) {
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divEdit').dialog('open');
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                }
            });                   
            });                
    }
```

On my controller, I am passing my Model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult fncBulkEdit(entEmployee objModel)
    {
        return PartialView("_Edit");
    }
```

The list of IDs on the model are declared under:

```
public virtual IList<long> lngEmployeeID { get; set; }
```

How will I am able to pass all checked checkboxes as IList IDs to my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use checkbox in foreach loop.
Use this in for loop  like below

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.ModelGroup.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ModelGroup[i].lngEmployee)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

[Check this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113118/multiple-checkboxes-in-razor-using-foreach)
Hope this helps..

Comment: Your code works pretty fine. I was also able to pass all the checked values by putting the grid under BeginForm method.