# Multiple checkboxes in razor always return false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkboxfor

I had this problem: [Multiple checkboxes in razor (using foreach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113118/multiple-checkboxes-in-razor-using-foreach)

I tried its solution. And it doesn't work for me. So hopefully you guys can help.

My View:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Messages.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateMessage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Messages[i].Activated, new {onchange = "this.form.submit();"});
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Messages[i].Text);
            }
        </td>
        <td>@Model.Messages[i].Text</td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Messages is a List of Message which has:

```
public string Text { get; set; }
public bool Activated { get; set; }
```

Controller POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateMessage(Domain.Entities.Message message)
{
    repository.UpdateMessage(message);

    return RedirectToAction("Settings_Message", "Home");
}
```

So I get a false bool and an empty string. Why?

Comment: You code makes no sense. The model in your view does not match the model in the POST method. And why do you have multiple forms in the view - a user can only submit one form at a time. And to trigger a submit an clickiung a checkbox id dreadful practice

Comment: Put you loop inside a single form with a submit button and change the model in the POST method to match the model in the view (except change the name of the parameter to anything other that the name of a property in the model) and allow the user to edit multiple items and post then all back in one action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code for this. It will work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateMessage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.CheckBox("Activated", Model.Messages[i].Activated, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" });
     @Html.Hidden("Text", Model.Messages[i].Text);                
}
```

Comment: You're my hero of the day. This works! Note: the `BeginForm` can be put into a `<table>` and a loop if you don't use "For" items.

Comment: This generates invalid html and is awful way to solve a bad design