# Checkboxes in ASP.NET 5 forms: for-loop is too slow, but foreach doesn't check properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, checkboxlist

I still haven't upgraded to .NET Core, and I am trying to render a list of checkboxes for my ViewModel collections in ASP.NET MVC. I read (here: [Multiple checkboxes in razor (using foreach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113118/multiple-checkboxes-in-razor-using-foreach)) that one cannot use a foreach loop to generate the checkboxes, because it will not bind the values correctly. However, the proposed solution of using a standard for-loop is way too slow:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Prop.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td class="js-export-checkbox">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Prop[i].IsChecked)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

So what am I supposed to do? Is there simply no solution here? I either forget on having properly checked boxes, or else I let my application take way too long to load?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That for loop should not take long to load. Are you sure the load time comes from your for loop? Aren't you running any JS script that may be slowing down your app?

Comment: No, I'm not using any JS. I compared the two options (for and foreach), and for some reason the for-loop is much slower. Is that uncommon?

Comment: It depends what you mean by slow. I'd expect they either for or foreach could knock out more checkboxes than a user would ever care to tick in their entire lifetime in a couple hundred milliseconds

Comment: For loop should be faster than foreach. Did you try to write your own HTML and pass attributes manually without using HTML helper CheckboxFor?

Comment: Yes, I did try my own HTML. I have no clue why it is slower with the for loop, but it is. Even if I compare for and foreach on something as simple as printing the number 2 for each object in my collection, the foreach loop is faster.